Export for Animation as Transparent Background Problem
Ok so I render with transparent, I turn on the container: quick time and video codec: QuickTime animation. if you see blue after rendering, don't worry about it, it's back to normal when I put it into the blender video editor, but the animation looks laggy. I changed it to mpeg-4, and the background is black.   How can I fix this?

please also add picture As an example.

"Background is black" is because Mpeg-4 doesn't support transparency. How do you mean to use the rendered footage, as a video by itself or are you combining with other footage? Best practice is to render to individual frames and import them as an image sequence into whatever video editor you prefer to finish your work in to composite with. Individual EXR or PNG will give you that transparency so that the final composite can be done and at that point, you render to your movie format of choice.

What do you mean, "the animation looks laggy"? A different video container seems very unlikely to fix anything of that nature.

Im going to try it out

It's works now.
